# sequential actions and DB state using slick; out of order behavior

Tags: scala, slick

Given a number of methods that pass tests and seem to be reliable, accessing and updating an independently incrementing column (incremented per record, so it's not an auto-incrementing column). e.g:

```
  def getVersion(id:Int): Future[Int] =  db.run(query.filter(_.id === id).map(o => o.version).result.head)  

def getAndIncrementVersion(id: Int): Future[Try[Int]] = {

    val incrementAction = sql"""UPDATE TABLE SET VERSION = VERSION + 1 WHERE ID = ${id}""".as[Int]
    val getVersionAction = query.filter(_.id === id).map(o => o.version).result.headOption
    val dbAction = incrementAction.andThen(getVersionAction)

    db.run(dbAction).map {
      case Some(i) => Success(i)
      case None => Failure[Int](new Exception("Error incrementing org counter"))
    }
  }
```

Now, if I call these methods in sequence, even if I resolve each future sequentially, I sometimes get out of order result, e.g.

```
   for {
     i <- getVersion(1)
     j <- getAndIncrementVersion(1)
     k <- getVersion(1)
    } yield (i,j,k)
```

which should yield, e.g. (71,Success(72), 72) will sometimes yield (71,72,71). Anyone have any ideas on why this would be happening?

Some more information:

- If I run this in a repeated loop it seems to happen on the first pass only.
- If I run this off of `sbt test` it will generally pass. If I'm in sbt and repeatedly invoke `test` it will probably fail after 3 or 4 times. There's a warning that the existing pool has not been released.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What DB are you using? Could you share the configuration or part of the code where the connection created? I think this is because autoCommit is set to false, so changes between read and write not visible to each other.

Comment: Ivan, that's a good guess, the increment is being called with "transactionally". The gets are not, but I wouldn't think they'd need to be?

Comment: this is connection level config,  meaning it will applied for all queries.

Comment: A good suggestion, but this is running w/autoocommit=true

Answer (score 1):

Your database may not guarantee when a change (from the update) is visible (to the `getVersion`). As you are running each part as an independent query, it's likely you'll get different results. If you need stricter behaviour, I suggest you combine the actions into a single action and run in a transaction.

For example (and apologies for typos--I've not tried to compile this):

```scala
 val action: DBIO[(Int,Int,Int)] = (for {
    i <- getVersionAction
    j <- incrementAction
    k <- getVersionAction
  } yield (i,j,k)).transactionally
```

I'd expect that to give you consistent results.

Comment: Richard, that's a good answer, but i'm concerned about state. The way I'm actually running this, in testing, is with a little function that realizes the futures sequentially : 

e.g. def waitFor[U](f: => Future[U]): U = Await.result(f, Duration.Inf)
so, waitFor(result1); waitFor(result2), ....

In that case I'd expect that once the futures finish they'd represent the state of the db. having stuff return out of order in that case is kind of troubling.

Comment: Double check those futures are not starting independently. E.g., `db.run` will start executing immediately. I think you've probably catered for that, otherwise you'd likely see the problem you do more often.